# Write SSH command over multiple lines

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, remote-access

I'm trying to remote login to a shell and execute a bunch of commands on the shell.
But to make it more readable, I'd like to place my code over multiple lines. How should I be doing this?

```
ssh -o <Option> -x -l <user> <host> " $long_command1; $long_command2; ....  "
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`ssh` is in fact just passing a string to the remote host.  There this string is given to a shell which is supposed to interpret it (the user's login shell, which is typically something like `bash`).  So whatever you want to execute needs to be interpretable by that remote login shell, that's the whole rule you have to stick to.

You can indeed just use newlines within the command string:

```
ssh alfe@sweethome "
  ls /home/alfe/whatever
  ping foreignhost
  date
  rm foobar
"
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019076/having-an-issue-passing-variables-to-subshell/32019393#32019393) I gave just recently about passing variables into ssh-remote shells.

Answer (score 33):

You can use the `Here Documents` feature of `bash`.
It is like:

```
ssh <remote-host> bash <<EOF
echo first command
echo second command
EOF
```

EOF marks the end of the input.

For further info: use `man bash` and search for `Here Documents`.

Edit: The only caveat is that using variables can be tricky, you have to escape the `$` to protect them to be evaluated on the remote host rather then the local shell. Like `\$HOSTNAME`. Otherwise works with everything that is run from bash and uses `stdin`.

Comment: is it the remote user's bash shell that'll be used here?

Comment: @ShyamaDorbala: Yes, remote bash. It actually works without `bash` as well, just "HereDocing" to ssh.

Comment: interesting. I'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: I like this solution, but I wish it worked better with indentation.  Leading spaces will break it (but leading tabs is OK).

Comment: As an alternative to the escaping, you can use <<"EOF" to stop the evaluation in the local shell.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like in the following example.

```
ssh -o <Option> -x -l <user> <host> '
pwd
whoami
ls
echo "$PATH"
'
```