# Continuous integration CI/CD with bash code

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have this code for my auto-deploy and I dont know why my code in git doesnt clone to my VPS server.
The code

```
# Set variables
SSH_USER=${SSH_USER}
SSH_HOST=${SSH_HOST}
PORT=${PORT}
EMAIL="test@email.com"
PROJECT_DIR="/var/www/public_html"
GIT_URL="git@gitlab.com:demo/web.git"
BRANCH="prod"

# Clone Git repository
if [ ! -d "$PROJECT_DIR" ]; then
    echo "Cloning Git repository..."
    ssh-keyscan -t rsa $SSH_HOST >> /home/root/.ssh/known_hosts
    git clone $GIT_URL $PROJECT_DIR
fi

# Pull latest changes from Git repository
echo "Pulling latest changes from Git repository..."
cd $PROJECT_DIR
git checkout $BRANCH
git pull

# Create file on server
echo "Creating file on server..."
touch text.txt

# Send email on success
echo "Deployment successful!"
echo "Sending email to $EMAIL..."
echo "Deployment successful for $PROJECT_DIR" | mail -s "Deployment successful" $EMAIL

exit 0
```

The ssh public key is in gitlab and the auth is already. The bash script is called in .gitlab-ci.yml
The code is before.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why my code in git doesnt clone *to* my VPS server

But your code (including the `git clone` command) is running on the GitLab runner, not on your VPS server (which might or might not have Git itself, by the way).

That means you need your [multiline commands to be executed through an SSH call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32082912/6309) over to your VPS.

Something like:

```bash
# Set variables
SSH_USER=${SSH_USER}
SSH_HOST=${SSH_HOST}
PORT=${PORT}
EMAIL="test@email.com"
PROJECT_DIR="/var/www/public_html"
GIT_URL="git@gitlab.com:demo/web.git"
BRANCH="prod"

# Clone Git repository and perform other tasks on the VPS server
ssh -p $PORT $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST << 'EOF'
    if [ ! -d "$PROJECT_DIR" ]; then
        echo "Cloning Git repository..."
        ssh-keyscan -t rsa gitlab.com >> /home/$SSH_USER/.ssh/known_hosts
        git clone $GIT_URL $PROJECT_DIR
    fi

    echo "Pulling latest changes from Git repository..."
    cd $PROJECT_DIR
    git checkout $BRANCH
    git pull

    echo "Creating file on server..."
    touch $PROJECT_DIR/text.txt
EOF

# Send email on success
echo "Deployment successful!"
echo "Sending email to $EMAIL..."
echo "Deployment successful for $PROJECT_DIR" | mail -s "Deployment successful" $EMAIL

exit 0
```